Use data from parent route's loader function
Say I have following route:
/us/new-york/books/15
In the parent route (one responsible for /us/new-york) I am fetching data for the region. I will need this data for all the routes under this URL.
Now inside my child route /us/new-york/books/15 I want to fetch data about book #15 but i need some data about region too
So actually I want to pass object from parent loader (or component) to child loader.
Is there a way to do it? Or how can I achieve it some other way?

Use the useMatches hook. It will return the loader data for all matching routes from root to leaf route.
https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-matches

The problem with is that (since it hook) it allowed to be used only in components. But I need the data inside loader function!

Yes, loaders are independent. They run in parallel. This is to prevent waterfalls. So unfortunately, you'll need to fetch the data again in each loader.
